# Why does Ionic default has-bouncing on ion-content to false?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I haven't been able to find documentation on why Ionic would want to default has-bouncing on ion-content to false.

It is my general understanding that the ionic has taken control of the scroll handling from native (ios and android). So, I am trying to understand the limitations of the has-bounce config option. I.e., what will/could break if I set has-bouncing to true?

`While we recommend using the custom Scroll features in Ionic in most cases, sometimes (for performance reasons) only the browser’s native overflow scrolling will suffice, and so we’ve made it easy to toggle between the Ionic scroll implementation and overflow scrolling.`
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/

Side note: It seems that android has a native method to handle this event? (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29).

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 2):

The property `has-bouncing` adds simply an effect when you scroll at the very top of the view or the bottom (see the image). It is set by default to `false` in Android and `true` in iOS because it is an iOS default comportement on native apps and not in Android.

[image: bouncing effect]

Comment: Thanks e666 for the answer. I'm trying to understand more on why it is an iOS native default and not an android native default. I.e., Does Android have some other native method to handle 'bounce'? Does 'bounce' break the native Android scroll? Does 'bounce' break the Ionic scroll (or some other component) on Android? Or, is this default as simple as a style choice by Android, so Ionic copied that style choice?

Comment: It is simple a style choice. You can enable it on Android if you want.